# Creating a redirecting proxy server with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, webserver

I am trying to create a proxy web server that redirects to the monitor.something.net using port 8443 and changelog.something.net using port 3000.

Comment: Go for it! Maybe try nginx instead. If you encounter any problems ask a question here ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain a litle more your question? You can try using the [http-proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy) package from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Comment: I am very new at making a proxy and I would like to know how to start it.

Comment: I suggest yo start reading the documentation of the npm package linked in the answer above.